# Como implementar login com atributo vindo de outra tabela com Devise no Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails4, devise

Atualmente tenho um Modelo **User** que tem um relacionamento `has_one` com **Customer**.

Na tabelas customers tenho o campo `CPF` que o usuário informa quando se cadastra.

Preciso implementar um login em que o usuário infoma o `e-mail` ou `CPF` para se logar no sistema.

Answer (score 0):

A documentação do Devise tem um exemplo de como resolver isso. Ele usa `username` ou `e-mail` para exemplificar, mas dá facilmente de adaptar para `CPF` ou `e-mail`. Dá uma olhada [aqui](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address) é um processo um pouco trabalhoso, por isso coloquei o link pra você de uma forte segura :) .

Então, para adaptar ao teu caso creio que você vai ter que alterar o comportamento do `find_for_database_authentication` onde você vai buscar o `CPF` na tabela `Customer`.

Comment: Obrigado Luiz !